# Finding kernel of a column matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I've got a matrix and linear mapping problem, giving me vector $v_1$ as
\begin{bmatrix}
        1\\
        0\\
        1\\
        \end{bmatrix}

and $v_2$ as 
\begin{bmatrix}
        0\\
        1\\
        1\\
        \end{bmatrix}
also, it gives me the mapping $f(x)=(x,v_1)v_1+(x,v_2)v_2$ while $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and the expression $(x,v_i)$ is dot product of $x$ and vector $v$

the problem asks me to find the basis of kernel of $f(x)$

so, I start thinking from $f(x)$. as dot product of vectors give scalar and I assume $x$ as 
\begin{bmatrix}
        x_1\\
        x_2\\
        x_3\\
        \end{bmatrix}
I'll get $f(x) =  
(x_1+x_3)\begin{bmatrix}
        0\\
        1\\
        1\\
        \end{bmatrix} + (x_2+x_3)
\begin{bmatrix}
        0\\
        1\\
        1\\
        \end{bmatrix}$

and do the multiplication to get 
$f(x)=\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0\\
        0 & 1\\
        1 & 1\\
        \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
        x_1+x_3\\
        x_2+x_3\\
        \end{bmatrix}$

and finally $f(x)=\begin{bmatrix}
        x_1+x_3\\
        x_2+x_3\\
        x_1+x_2+2x_3\\
        \end{bmatrix}$

then to find kernel I should take the matrix equal to $0$ and find the kernel but I cannot find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guide:

$$f(x) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}  x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3\end{bmatrix}$$

Consider the matrix, $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 2\end{bmatrix}$$

Sum of the first two rows give us the third row and the first two rows are linearly independent.

Solve this linear system by letting $x_3=t$, express $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $t$.
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}  x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: I solved it and get the answer as $\begin{bmatrix}
        -1\\
        -1\\
        1\\
        \end{bmatrix}$. I understood your method well like I was really close. Thanks a lot